# Code for Calculator in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to build a calculator like Windows Calculator.
I have done the following coding but I dont know how use code e.KeyChar for Equal(=) when the user presses the Enter Button.

```
if(e.KeyChar == 40)
{
    MessageBox.Show("you press enter");
}
```

but this code not run in program

Comment: Could be case sensitive issue? What error do you get?

Comment: The Enter key will be < 32

Comment: "but this code not run in program" - Thats a very general statement.

Comment: I think he means he can't compile. At least he shouldn't be able to, as `40` is not a `char`.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - `char` is implicitly convertible to `int`.

Answer (score 13):

Use the `KeyUp` or `KeyDown` events and query

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
```

Comment: I'm thinking the `KeyUp` event is more appropriate here. The problem with the `KeyDown` event is that it's repeated when the key is held down.

Comment: Are you sure about the event being repeated? You can also use `KeyUp`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
   if (e.KeyChar == 13)
   {
     // Enter key pressed
   }
```

Comment: The cast is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Key Pressed!");
}
```